# Почему space-between прижимает к центру?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Я решил сделать шапку сайту, но свойство `justify-content:space-between`, судя по некоторым источникам, должен прижать элементы к краям, но у меня всё с точностью наоборот - все элементы прижались к центру.

```css
.flex{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    width:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
 <div class="one">1</div>
 <div class="two">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: А почему у вас в примере `justify-content: start` написано?

Comment: Сори, поправка.

Comment: А теперь у вас опечатка в слове `beetwen`

Comment: Уже поправлено.

Comment: А теперь в примере всё успешно прижимается, а по центру пусто, как и должно быть. Так что вопрос теперь непонятен

Comment: Вопрос не просто непонятен, а решён.

Comment: Ну тогда вопрос отправляется на закрытие по причине непонятной сути и отсутствия примера проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

?

```css
.flex__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex__item {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex__container">
  <div class="flex__item">1</div>
  <div class="flex__item">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Отлично! Всё работает так, как я и хотел. На данный момент я пока не могу отметить ответ как найлучший. Спасибо большое!